# How to Add Objects from Vector to ListBuffer in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-programming, playframework-2.2

I am not Able to Print newPStat List's Elements on console, After doing following simple transformation, 
Its damn Simple and Still I am missing some very non trivial thing.

```
...
val newPStat = List[PSObject]()

S1ServiceObject.getPS.onComplete({
        case Success(pSList) => {
          logger.info("Number of Ps - " + pSList.size)
            pSList.foreach{
              pfS => {
              newPStat ++ List(new PSObject(pfS.pfNameRemote, pfS.impRemote,
                  pfS.actCRemote, pfS.actARemote) )
                println("prx Size "+newPStat.size)
              }
            }
          }
        case Failure(exception) => {
          logger.error("Error while trying to get PS  - " + exception.getMessage)
        }
      })


case class PSObject(pfName: String, imp : BigDecimal, actC: Int, actA: Int)

// printing the object's elements

newPStat.foreach{x => println("prax: "+x.toString)}
```

As you can see above function calls
Following Function, which is a Service layer Func. which Returns Future[Vector[]]

```
def getPS: Future[Vector[PSObjectDTO]]= {
    getPSData
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never actually changing the `newPStat` list. This line in fact does nothing:

```
newPStat ++ List(new PSObject(pfS.pfNameRemote, pfS.impRemote, pfS.actCRemote, pfS.actARemote) )
```

You are making a new list but never assign it to anything, as shown by this REPL example:

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> a ++ List(4)
res9: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> a
res10: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

So you will need to change `newPStat` from `val` to `var` and reassign it to the new list:

```
newPStat = newPStat ++ List(new PSObject(pfS.pfNameRemote, pfS.impRemote, pfS.actCRemote, pfS.actARemote) )
```

Also since you are dynamically building a list, I would instead reccomend an `ArrayBuffer`:

```
scala> val a = collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Int]
a: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()

scala> a.append(1)

scala> a.append(2)

scala> a.toArray
res13: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)
```

A more idiomatic approach would be to use a `map` instead of a `foreach`:

```
newPStat = pSList.map{pfS => new PSObject(pfS.pfNameRemote, pfS.impRemote, pfS.actCRemote, pfS.actARemote)}.toList
```

Comment: Hi evan, thanks for the answer, but when using map i am getting following compileation error....

Expression of type Vector[PSObject] doesn't conform to the expected type List[PSObject].

Comment: Try adding a `toList` at the end of the map expression